# Magento Enterprise Edition Upgrade from 2.3.5-p2 to 2.4.0 getting error

Tags: magento2, enterprise, versionupgrade

I am a newbie for the Magento enterprise edition. I am upgrading Magento 2.3.5-p2 to Magento 2.4.0 in Enterprise Edition.

Following commands used with MySQL 5.7 and php7.3:

composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
composer update

During 'composer update' getting an error from the Magento module.

[image]

I have tried with included Magento keys in the auth.json file. But it's not worked. Any another solution for this error. How to resolve this.

The "http://xxrepo.xxx.com/dist/magento/module-ui/magento-module-ui-101.2.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Please let me know if anyone knows how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run

> composer require Magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update

You can use the below method to upgrade the commerce edition, eg if you want to upgrade to 2.4.3 then the below command will be used.

> composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.3 <2.4.4"
> --no-update -vvv
>
> composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage -vvv
>
> composer update -vvv

After this, you need to commit your changed files and merge them with integration or staging instances.

more detailed information you can find [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html)

Comment: If I run this above comment it's adding 'Magento-cloud-metapackage' in the composer.json file. It's not changing the existing 'magento/product-enterprise-edition' version. If I run this below command only it's changing magento version.             composer require Magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update   **https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html**

Comment: Any answer for this?